# Como organizar a API REST e o frontend do site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express.js

Estou criando um site Single Page Application, para isso, criei uma API Restful em Node.js que faz todas as ações no banco de dados, login, envio de emails e etc. Pensei em criar uma pasta "public" no meu projeto e colocar lá o meu front-end. Porém acho que alguma hora vou ter conflito entre as rotas do Node.js e do meu front-end. Pensei em deixar a API rodando em uma porta e o front-end rodando em outra porta. Como se fossem projetos separados.

Qual a forma mais utilizada na organização de projetos que usam Single Page Application, API's restful e etc?

Comment: Entendo que esse assunto provavelmente seria melhor discutido no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), pois não há uma solução ideal que atenda qualquer um. Depende muito da opinião e experiência de cada desenvolvedor, e principalmente da proposta individual de cada projeto. É uma dúvida válida, talvez as respostas não possam ser tão válidas assim, pois há uma grande chance de a pergunta atrair "depoimentos pessoais" que poderiam ser confundidos como respostas técnicas, o que não é tão adequado para o formato de perguntas e respostas objetivas do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando eu crio aplicações deste tipo eu faço da forma como você está construindo. Deixo a minha aplicação em node rodando em um container e minha aplicação web rodando em outro. Acho que é a melhor forma de fazer essa comunicação entre eles (utlizando no front-end o vue.js). Já que o node está servindo uma API para o seu front-end não vejo problemas em fazer desta forma.

Talvez seja legal também separar o node e aplicação em servidores separados. Mas acho que não é o seu intuito.

Não há uma forma "certa" de construir algo deste tipo. Vai depender muito da forma como você gosta de construir sua aplicação e [importante] como ela será utilizada. Se você for utiliza-la em outos tipos de aplicação, como em um aplicativo android/ios, talvez seja melhor separar a aplicação back-end da front-end para evitar o que você disse: conflito.

Não há uma resposta certa para essa pergunta, mas acho que deu para entender. Abraços! :D

Comment: Valeu, Lucas. Também estou usando Vue para construir o front-end da aplicação. Valeu pela resposta, bem esclarecedora.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! Abraços!!